# How to divide the second element of a list by a number

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of number:

```
{
 {0.00008, 342.1}, {0.00016, 221.633}, {0.00024, 134.267}, 
 {0.00032,95.3}, {0.0004,54.4333}, {0.00048,27.1667}, {0.00056,10.8}, 
 {0.00064, 1.03333}, {0.00072,1.1}, {0.0008,1.46667}, {0.00088,2.96667}, 
 {0.00096,1.13333}, {0.00104,0.233333}, {0.00112, 0.}, {0.0012,2.9}, 
 {0.00128,3.4}, {0.00136,1.23333}, {0.00144,1.33333}, {0.00152,2.3}, 
 {0.0016,5.3}, {0.00168,5.53333}, {0.00176,1.83333}, {0.00184,1.63333}, 
 {0.00192,6.36667}, {0.002,6.93333}, {0.00208,2.36667}, {0.00216,2.66667}, 
 {0.00224,5.3}, {0.00232,6.26667}, {0.0024,4.46667}, {0.00248,3.8}, 
 {0.00256,4.5}, {0.00264,5.36667}, {0.00272,4.9}, {0.0028,2.83333}, 
 {0.00288,3.16667}, {0.00296,4.63333}, {0.00304,4.83333}, {0.00312,5.}, 
 {0.0032,5.66667}, {0.00328,5.}, {0.00336,4.13333}, {0.00344,5.13333}, 
 {0.00352,4.6}, {0.0036,4.23333}, {0.00368,5.66667}, {0.00376,5.6}, 
 {0.00384,3.8}, {0.00392,4.33333}, {0.004,5.8}, {0.00408,6.03333}, 
 {0.00416,5.33333}, {0.00424,5.}, {0.00432,4.6}, {0.0044,4.4}, 
 {0.00448,5.43333}, {0.00456,5.23333}, {0.00464,5.36667}, {0.00472,5.63333}, 
 {0.0048,4.33333}, {0.00488,4.33333}, {0.00496,5.76667}, {0.00504,5.8}
}
```

I'm trying to normalize the second elements by dividing them by the max element (in the specific case 342.1). Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: `max = Max@list[[All, 2]]; list2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]]/max} & /@ list;` Alternatively, `list2 = (list /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y/max})`

Answer (score 13):

#### [`Normalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html) + [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html)

```
list2 = SubsetMap[Normalize[#, Max]&, list, {All, 2}]
```

> {{0.00008, 1.}, {0.00016, 0.64786}, {0.00024, 0.392479}, {0.00032,
> 0.278574}, {0.0004, 0.159115}, {0.00048, 0.0794116}, {0.00056,
> 0.0315697}, {0.00064, 0.00302055}, {0.00072, 0.00321543}, {0.0008,
> 0.00428726}, {0.00088, 0.00867194}, {0.00096, 0.00331286}, {0.00104,
> 0.000682061}, {0.00112, 0.}, {0.0012, 0.00847705}, {0.00128,
> 0.00993861}, {0.00136, 0.00360517}, {0.00144, 0.00389749}, {0.00152,
> 0.00672318}, {0.0016, 0.0154925}, {0.00168, 0.0161746}, {0.00176,
> 0.00535905}, {0.00184, 0.00477442}, {0.00192, 0.0186106}, {0.002,
> 0.020267}, {0.00208, 0.00691806}, {0.00216, 0.007795}, {0.00224,
> 0.0154925}, {0.00232, 0.0183182}, {0.0024, 0.0130566}, {0.00248,
> 0.0111079}, {0.00256, 0.013154}, {0.00264, 0.0156874}, {0.00272,
> 0.0143233}, {0.0028, 0.00828217}, {0.00288, 0.00925656}, {0.00296,
> 0.0135438}, {0.00304, 0.0141284}, {0.00312, 0.0146156}, {0.0032,
> 0.0165644}, {0.00328, 0.0146156}, {0.00336, 0.0120822}, {0.00344,
> 0.0150053}, {0.00352, 0.0134464}, {0.0036, 0.0123745}, {0.00368,
> 0.0165644}, {0.00376, 0.0163695}, {0.00384, 0.0111079}, {0.00392,
> 0.0126669}, {0.004, 0.0169541}, {0.00408, 0.0176362}, {0.00416,
> 0.01559}, {0.00424, 0.0146156}, {0.00432, 0.0134464}, {0.0044,
> 0.0128617}, {0.00448, 0.0158823}, {0.00456, 0.0152977}, {0.00464,
> 0.0156874}, {0.00472, 0.0164669}, {0.0048, 0.0126669}, {0.00488,
> 0.0126669}, {0.00496, 0.0168567}, {0.00504, 0.0169541}}

#### [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) + [`Normalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html)

```
l3 = list;
l3[[All, 2]] //= Normalize[#, Max] &;

l3 == l2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Alternatively, modify `list` in place using `ApplyTo` and `Normalize`:

```
list[[All,2]] //= Normalize[#, Max]&;
list == l2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 11):

With your list stored in `data`, then

```
data[[All, 2]] = Normalize[data[[All, 2]], Max];
```

Here is a visual confirmation of the normalization:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: scatter plot of normalized data]

Answer (score 10):

I'll call your list `theData`. I might do something like this:

```
With[
  {max2nd = Max[theData[[All, 2]]]},
  SubsetMap[#/max2nd &, theData, {All, 2}]]
```

Or this, which might be a little clearer:

```
With[
  {max2nd = Max[theData[[All, 2]]]},
  SubsetMap[Rescale[#, {0, max2nd}] &, theData, {All, 2}]]
```

You could, of course, inline this directly without With:

```
SubsetMap[Rescale[#, {0, Max[theData[[All, 2]]]}] &, theData, {All, 2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
lst.{{1,0},{0,1/Max[lst[[All,2]]]}}
```

check:

```
(lst.{{1,0},{0,1/Max[lst[[All,2]]]}})==SubsetMap[Normalize[#, Max]&, lst, {All, 2}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** Thanks to @lericr for pointing out the lack of generality in the original answer.

With `data` as in the OP:

```
alist = data[[All, 1]];
blist = Rescale[#, MinMax[#], {Min[#]/Max[#], 1}] &@data[[All, 2]]
ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {data, 
  Transpose[{alist, blist}]}
```

---

In order to illustrate usage in the presence of bipolar data, consider a random 1-D list called `alist`:

```
SeedRandom[11];
alist = RandomReal[{-10, 9}, 20]
MinMax[alist]
```

> {-9.65232, 6.29926}

This will be scaled between 1 and the min value getting divided by the max value of the list.

```
blist = Rescale[alist, MinMax[alist], {Min[alist]/Max[alist], 1}]
```

[image]

This is a more generic answer compared to the original attempt while using the same `Transpose` technique.

---

**Original attempt**

From the docs:

```
> Rescale[list]  rescales each element of list to run from 0 to 1 over
> the range Min[list] to Max[list].
```

---

Your data (call it `data`) has two columns:

The first column is: `data[[All, 1]]`

The second column is: `data[[All, 2]]`

Rescale 2nd column: `Rescale[data[[All, 2]]]`

Given these pieces, a `Transpose` does the job:

```
res2 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Rescale[data[[All, 2]]]}]
```

This can be plotted using:

```
ListPlot[res2[[All, 2]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I think this would only work if the min of the second column was 0. So, it does in fact work in this specific case (because the second column min is indeed 0), but it doesn't generalize (unless I've misunderstood your solution).

Comment: That's right. I should try and submit a more general answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{0.00008, 342.1}, {0.00016, 221.633}, {0.00024, 134.267}, {0.00032, 95.3}};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> x / Max[list], {All, 2}] @ list
```

> {{0.00008, 1.}, {0.00016, 0.64786}, {0.00024, 0.392479}, {0.00032,
> 0.278574}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{0.00008, 342.1}, {0.00016, 221.633}, {0.00024, 134.267}, {0.00032, 95.3}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, 2} :> list[[i, 2]]/Max[list]]
```

> `{{0.00008, 1.}, {0.00016, 0.64786}, {0.00024, 0.392479}, {0.00032, 0.278574}}`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly. You want to divide every vector by the greater element in it. For example the first vector is 342.1 and second is 221.633. Am I correct? If so, you can try to create a list of "greater value original array" then divide by them respectively (let me assume variable `a` is your input list):

````
max=Map[Max[#] &, a];
MapThread[Divide, {a, m}]
{{2.3385*10^-7, 1.}, {7.21914*10^-7, 1.}, {1.78748*10^-6, 
  1.}, {3.35782*10^-6, 1.}, {7.34844*10^-6, 1.}, {0.0000176687, 
  1.}, {0.0000518519, 1.}, {0.000619357, 1.}, {0.000654545, 
  1.}, {0.000545453, 1.}, {0.000296629, 1.}, {0.000847061, 
  1.}, {0.00445715, 1.}, {1., 0.}, {0.000413793, 1.}, {0.000376471, 
  1.}, {0.00110271, 1.}, {0.00108, 1.}, {0.00066087, 
  1.}, {0.000301887, 1.}, {0.000303615, 1.}, {0.000960002, 
  1.}, {0.00112653, 1.}, {0.000301571, 1.}, {0.000288462, 
  1.}, {0.000878872, 1.}, {0.000809999, 1.}, {0.000422642, 
  1.}, {0.000370213, 1.}, {0.000537313, 1.}, {0.000652632, 
  1.}, {0.000568889, 1.}, {0.000491925, 1.}, {0.000555102, 
  1.}, {0.000988236, 1.}, {0.000909473, 1.}, {0.000638849, 
  1.}, {0.000628966, 1.}, {0.000624, 1.}, {0.000564706, 
  1.}, {0.000656, 1.}, {0.000812904, 1.}, {0.00067013, 
  1.}, {0.000765217, 1.}, {0.000850394, 1.}, {0.000649411, 
  1.}, {0.000671429, 1.}, {0.00101053, 1.}, {0.000904616, 
  1.}, {0.000689655, 1.}, {0.000676243, 1.}, {0.00078, 1.}, {0.000848,
   1.}, {0.00093913, 1.}, {0.001, 1.}, {0.00082454, 1.}, {0.000871338,
   1.}, {0.000864596, 1.}, {0.00083787, 1.}, {0.00110769, 
  1.}, {0.00112615, 1.}, {0.000860115, 1.}, {0.000868966, 1.}}

```
````